# JPA OneToOne like dependency

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm trying Play Framework, now I have this situation:

I have a SuperUser who is a Person with power, and I want to do this Persona entity like FK and so like primary key for SuperUsuario entity, now I have it:

```
@Entity(name = "SUPERUSUARIO")
public class Superusuario extends Model {

    @OneToOne
    public Persona persona;

    public Superusuario(Persona persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }
```

but the framework create a field ID por any entity, how can I get Persona like PK for SuperUsuario??

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. Why would you want to specify a PK for this? Really? Why would you PK be better than the ID field PlayFramework generates for you? If you want, you can add a index for performance b ut I doubt that will help you anyway.
2. Why do it that way? A superuser is a person with power. Thus create a superuser containing a user? Why not use the possibilites giving by Java and all the other object oriented programming languages by the way? Polymorphism. You superuser could be an extended user. Much better that way.

Comment: 1. I want to specify a this FK so like and PK because the SuperUsuario depends of Person and it's unique                                            2. Exactly SuperUser is an extension's User for this reason this have a direct relation with User entity

Comment: And if I understand you comment right, (which is really difficult), my answer is doing exactly what you want. User still is unique, the link will still exist between the two.